# jQuery - Follow the cursor with a DIV

Tags: html, jquery, mouse-cursor

How can I use jQuery to follow the cursor with a DIV?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can't follow the cursor with a `DIV`, but you can draw a `DIV` when moving the cursor!

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#your_div_id').css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

That div must be off the float, so `position: absolute` should be set.

Comment: I had some trouble with getting this working correctly.  Using a pure jQuery solution rather than `.css()` ended up working for me.  Inside the function, use this line instead:  `$('#your_div_id').offset({left: e.page, top: e.pageY});`

Comment: Nice demo @Reigel ! I modified it a bit to show a horizontal line (http://jsfiddle.net/rg8S8/). I'm planning to use this to help people read plots (they are png images, so not much I can do to show values as text, automatically). It should work a lot better than "eyeballing" values.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need jQuery for this. Here's a simple working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>box-shadow-experiment</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box-shadow-div{
                position: fixed;
                width: 1px;
                height: 1px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                background-color:black;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black;
                top: 49%;
                left: 48.85%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                var bsDiv = document.getElementById("box-shadow-div");
                var x, y;
    // On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                    x = event.clientX;
                    y = event.clientY;                    
                    if ( typeof x !== 'undefined' ){
                        bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                        bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box-shadow-div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I chose `position: fixed;` so scrolling wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me. Has a nice delayed action going on.

```
var $mouseX = 0, $mouseY = 0;
var $xp = 0, $yp =0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $mouseX = e.pageX;
    $mouseY = e.pageY;    
});

var $loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
$xp += (($mouseX - $xp)/12);
$yp += (($mouseY - $yp)/12);
$("#moving_div").css({left:$xp +'px', top:$yp +'px'});  
}, 30);
```

Nice and simples

Comment: His answer is providing something new, a damping effect